# how to get a part of attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, html

Q:

If i have  a div with a specific class name i know , and have a title(attribute),How can i get a specific part of this title value with Jquery??

the source code:(from fire bug)

```
<div style="height: 21px; width: 90%; left: 0%;" class="rsApt" title="WPF[003]" id="rs_7_0">
                                            <div style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 102);" class="rsAptOut">
                                                <div class="rsAptMid">
                                                    <div class="rsAptIn">
                                                        <div class="rsAptContent">
                                                            WPF[003]<a href="#" class="rsAptDelete" style="visibility: hidden;">delete</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><div style="z-index: 80;" class="rsAptResize">
                                                        <!-- -->
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

if i wanna to get this part `003` of the title attribute(may be other number in the other Divs with the same class), how to do that? and if there is any general way to get a part of string, this will be great..

i wanna to set the selected value of a drop down list with this value according to this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
            if ($(e.target).hasClass('rsAptDelete')) {
            }
            else {
                 $("#ddl_editCourse").val('The accessed value of the Div title');

                ShowDialog(true);
                e.preventDefault();

            }

        });
```

how to do this with this line of code??

**EDITED**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ddl_editCourse").val(new RegExp(/\d{3}/).exec( $(".rsApt").attr("title") ));
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but i don't wanna the whole value of title  i wanna just the 003 part for example , how to get this part only and if there is any general way?

Comment: i don't know why each time the selected value is 002?? according to this reg exp

Comment: If the HTML in your question is true, it should be `003`.

Comment: thanks , but it 's so weird , i don't know what is the problem?

Comment: According to my code when click on `.rsAptContent`,and put the following line
`alert( new RegExp(/\d{3}/).exec($(".rsApt").attr("title")) );`
i get `002` all the time even i click on div has title other than `002`.

Comment: When i try this line of Code:
`alert($(".rsApt").attr("title"));`
I get `sql[002]` all the time even though the .rsApt(which was clicked on) title is not that value!!!

Comment: Ahh, I think I get it. Change `$(".rsApt")` to `$(this).parents(".rsApt")` and I think it will work.

Comment: Great , Great , Great ,,, it works finally thank us so much , i will be grateful if u explain how this statement fix my problem. thanks again.

Comment: It gets the parent `.rsApt` of the `.rsAptContent` that was clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\[(.*)\\]");
$("#ddl_editCourse").val(regex.exec($(".rsApt").attr("title"))[1]);
```

Comment: I get this error :

`regex.exec($(".rsApt").attr("title")) is null`

Comment: Please verify the code that you posted in the question. In my answer I am assuming that, it is the exact markup that you have in your actual code.

Comment: Note that if you are using the string constructor of `RegExp`, you need to escape the back slashes: `new RegExp("\\[(.*)\\]")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression here, or you can use the `substring` and `indexOf` methods.

If you know the number will always be within square brackets, then you can look for them using indexOf, the get the substring based on those indices:

```
var title = $('#rsApt').attr('title');
var opening = title.indexOf('[');
var closing = title.indexOf(']');
var number  = title.substring(opening, closing);
```

// print out the number

```
$("#ddl_editCourse").val('The accessed value of the Div title: ' + number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ddl_editCourse").val( $(".rsApt").attr("title").replace(/\D/g,'') );
```